# Why I get this error in emacs when starting Gnus

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

nntp (news) open error: '>> news/nntp Name or service not known)'.

I am runing ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnus requires that you have configured a news server to use, and I think it defaults to "news", which doesn't exist in your local search domains (likely given to you via DHCP from your ISP or local router).  You can set it by putting the following lines in your ~/.gnus file:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "my cool server" 
                           (nntp-address "PUT.ADDRESS.HERE"))
```

Change *PUT.ADDRESS.HERE* to the full name of your nntp server.